# WHMCS: disable Single Sign-On and Change Password

Tags: php, add-on, whmcs

We are not providing our customers the access to the cPanel and they only have the WHMCS client area logins.

So, whoever having Client Area Access can change the cPanel Password and even login to cPanel directly via Single Sign On (added in WHMCS 6.2.x).

Now, we need to disable the WHMCS "Single Sign-On" and "Change Password" Options from WHMCS.

For Now, we're using the `mode rewrite` to disable the single sign-on request
here is the working code (I know, its not the permanent solution).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/clientarea\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*?dosinglesignon=1.*?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php  [R=301,L]
```

But, there is no way to disable the change password option.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template for the cPanel specific product area display is stored in:

modules/servers/cpanel/templates/

You can override this with a custom file in your theme:

http://docs.whmcs.com/Working_with_Module_Templates

The sidebar links can be hidden with a hook:

http://docs.whmcs.com/Client_Area_Sidebars_Cheatsheet

Hope those details help.

Comment: html/css hide will never work. if you do so, user can manually enter the URL to access the cpanel.

Comment: e.g: https://domain.com/clientarea.php?action=productdetails&id=xxx&dosinglesignon=1

this URL will allow anyone to signin to cPanel.